# command line to hide top bar of gnome ubuntu 22.04

Tags: command-line, 22.04, appearance

there are a lot of tips for hide the top bar, but it just works by GUI or just for older version of Ubuntu up to 20.04. I searched a lot but there is no solution with command line for Ubuntu 22.04+.

Surprisingly, There is built-in solution for hide side bar in settings, but excludes the top bar.

Please note that:

If it is not possible with CLI, that's OK. I just want to make sure is there a way or not with CL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: all options in gnome are stored in `dconf` and can be set on command line using the `gsettings` command. Just find the correct 'key' and 'value'.  See `dconf-editor`

Comment: option is likely `/org/{yourdesktop}/panel-autohide` with a true of false. where {yourdesktop} needs to be your desktop name (ie. like cinnamon)

Comment: you said dconf-editor, it's mean not CLI? or there is CLI to "talk to" dconf-editor?

Comment: see my previous comment: `gsettings`.

Comment: thank you, i will dig it right now. thank you so much